# Slide-out sidebar menu без storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios7

Есть ли какие-то библиотеки для Slide-out sidebar menu без storyboard? Все, что нахожу, работает со сторибордом. Нужно программно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот эту. Сам использую в своем проекте.
https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Comment: Спасибо. Но если честно, я немного зеленоват в этом деле, никак не могу понять, как им правильно пользоваться. Уже и пример нашел, но опять же с xib-ами, вообщем не работает пока что. А я пытаюсь создать интерфейс полностью программно. Нашел какой-то JDSideMenu, но он немного глючноват.